# Want to extract a specfic jar file from an ear file and store it in a specific directory

Tags: java, jar

I have an ear file that has multiple jar files.  I would like to extract the jars and store them in a specific directory.
This command extracts one of the jars but it places it in the current directory.

```
C:\TestDir> jar xf Test.ear Assigned.jar
```

This will extract the jar, Assigned.jar to the directory TestDir.
According to some of the documentation, it states that if you add a directory path to the jar you want to extract it will put it in the directory, if the directory does not exist, it will create it. But I have found that not to be the case.
So if I have something like this:

```
 C:\TestDir> jar xf Test.ear C:\ExtractedJars\Assigned.jar
```

Is it possible to direct the output into a specific directory.
If it won't create the directory on the fly, then I will create it first.
But I would like to be able to direct the jars to a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to extract file to specific location using jar.
jar tool accepts 2 arguments:

1. archive file
2. names of archived files to extract

so you cannot extract it to specific location.

Try to extract files with some command line script, that will do extraction first, and then copy file to specific location.

Comment: OK.  I can extract the jar files and they are stored in the current location.